# Python mysql: how do loop through table and regex-replacing field?

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to iterate a table, fetch the rows in which a field has a pattern, then update the same row with a match group.

The following code runs without error, the two `print` lines before `update` clause output correct values. I have followed similar answers to come up the `update` clause, the logic seems right to me. However the code does not work, i.e., no rows updated. Where did I do wrong? Thanks,

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import MySQLdb

pattern = re.compile('@(.*)@.*$')

conn = MySQLdb.connect(
    host='localhost', user='root',
    passwd='password', db='j314', charset='utf8')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(
    """select `id`, `created_by_alias` from w0z9v_content where `catid` = 13 AND `created_by_alias` regexp "^@.*@.*$" limit 400""")

aliases = cursor.fetchall()
for alias in aliases:
    newalias = pattern.match(alias[1])
    if newalias.group(1) is not None:
        # print alias[0]
        # print newalias.group(1)
        cursor.execute("""
        update w0z9v_content set created_by_alias = %s where id = %s""", (newalias.group(1), alias[0]))
conn.close
```

Comment: What is printed? What did you expect?

Comment: @PavelAnossov for example: one such row has the value for `created_by_alias`: `@dapigu@Twitter`, the print out is Line 1(`alias[0]`): `2`, Line 2 (`newalias.group(1)`) : `dapigu`, I expect row 2 of `created_by_alias` value changed to `dapigu`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the question, thought you wrote "incorrect".

Comment: Could autocommit be disabled? Does a `cursor.execute('COMMIT')` at the end perform the updates?

Comment: @PavelAnossov Beautiful! That did the trick, please make it an answer and I'll accept it;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`autocommit`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit) is probably globally disabled on the server.

Execute either `COMMIT` after your updates, or `SET autocommit=1` at the beginning of the session.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Also, you're not actually closing the connection, you forgot to *call* close:

`conn.close()`